# Hibernate criteria java annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, many-to-many, criteria

Im new at Hibernate and i have a problem that i can't solve, i take a look at similar questions but i haven't luck...

I have a table (lets call it T1) and another table (lets call it T2). T1 have a relation with T2 and T2 same with T1, so they have a many to many relation so i created a bridge table (lets call it T1_T2).

T1.id <----> T1_T2.T1id <----> T2.id
T2.id <----> T1_T2.T2id <----> T1.id

My question is the next: How i should build my java clases (T1, T1_T2, T2) and make a query with criteria, only giving **one** id (of any of the 2 tables) as a parameter?

Hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: There are so many examples in internet, have you tried any of them?

Comment: Yes but mostly are hql, not criteria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the annotation @JoinTable after @ManyToMany pointing the t1_t2 table for relation. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Let me put some example, One User has many permissions and one Permission has many Users

User

```
@Table(name="USER")
public class User() {

      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(
        name="USER_GROUP",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID")})
      private List<Group> groups;
      ...

  }
```

Permission

```
@Table(name="GROUP")
public class Group(){

      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @JoinTable(
        name="USER_GROUP",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")})
      private List<Users> users;
      ...

 }
```

Comment: And what i should put in t1_t2?

Comment: @Ralsho, t1_t2 is maintained by hibernate for many-to-many association, hibernate will put the foreign keys for you. It is just a join table.